# The columns in 'table' do not match an existing primary key or unique constraint

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, foreign-key-relationship

Consider two database tables, `tbl_One` & `tbl_Two`.

`tbl_One`'s primary keys are: `A`, `B` & `E` columns

`tbl_Two`'s primary keys are: `B` & `C`.

I don't want any values in table `tbl_Two` column `B` that do not exist in table `tbl_One` column `B`.

Ideally, I want column `B` to be foreign key, but when I try to create this I get the following error message:

> The columns in table 'tbl_One' do not match an existing primary key
>   or UNIQUE constraint.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: In tbl_One, are the three columns A,B,E together a composite key?  Your statement that there are "primary keys" (plural) is a bit confusing.

Comment: What table is MasterData? tbl_One or tblTwo?

Comment: @Gizmo it is tbl_One, I corrected the error msg.

Comment: @AaronPalmer I don't know what is a composite key, I just selected 3 columns, right click and selected primary key.

Comment: In your scenario, you have not identified `B` by itself as a PK in either table.  So `B` by itself cannot be used as a FK in a relationship with these two tables.  Basically, a FK in one table must be the PK in the table being referenced.

Comment: And to clarify about composite key, it is a Primary Key that is composed of multiple columns, created in SQL Server exactly as you ahve described.  These three columns together describe a unique record, but any one on its own may not necessarily ensure uniqueness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Caveat: Without more detail, I'm flying almost blind, my answer is based on what I could assume from your question.*

If you really want to create a foreign key to a non-primary key, it MUST be a column that has a unique constraint on it.

**From [Books Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464(v=SQL.105).aspx):**

> A FOREIGN KEY constraint does not have to be linked only to a PRIMARY
>   KEY constraint in another table; it can also be defined to reference
>   the columns of a UNIQUE constraint in another table.

In this instance, you would need column B in tbl_One to be unique, either by it being the primary key or having a Unique constraint on it.

**UNIQUE constraint:**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_One
(
    A int,
    B int UNIQUE,
    E int
    CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_One] PRIMARY KEY 
    (
        A ASC,
        B ASC,
        E ASC
    )
)
```

If it's the case that the data in column B is not unique, you can create a function based CHECK constraint to achieve a similar effect.

**Function(Not tested):**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckFunction(@B int)
RETURNS INT
AS BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT CASE COUNT(*) 
                   WHEN 0 THEN 0 
                   ELSE 1 
                   END 
              FROM tbl_One 
             WHERE B=@B)
END
```

**CHECK constraint:**

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_Two
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_CheckFunction
CHECK (dbo.CheckFunction(B) = 1)
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/13dc7d/3) that demonstrates this.

Thanks for pointing out the referential integrity issue Damien, an AFTER DELETE trigger *can* help get around this, but there are shortcomings. Here is a good [discussion on referential integrity](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1508/foreign-key-vs-trigger-referential-integrity-in-sql-server/) managed with foreign keys vs triggers.

Comment: Of course, the function version is rather incomplete because it doesn't prevent anyone from deleting the last `B` row in `tbl_one` after rows have been added to `tbl_two`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a foreign key for field B in table B, remove field A, E 's primary key, create the relation then reset the primary keys back to those two fields.